# Rasterize resets the PlotRange?

Tags: graphics, image, rasterize

I used in my calculations zome polynomials evaluated on a grid with `Array` command and characteristic functions of some polygons, which I evaluated using `Rasterize` function and I realised that the results of these two sampling paradigms are not consistent. It looks like `Rasterize` ignores or adjusts the `PlotRange` option. The best it can be illustrated by this MWE:

```
Manipulate[ 
  graphics = 
    Graphics[{GrayLevel[0], Disk[{0, 0}, .8]}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True]; 
  raster = 
    Rasterize[
      Graphics[{GrayLevel[0], Disk[{0, 0}, .8]}, 
        PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 
      RasterSize -> {picsize, picsize}, 
      ImageSize -> {picsize, picsize}];
  array = 
    Image @ Boole @ 
      Array[{##} ∉ Disk[{0, 0}, .8] &, {picsize, picsize}, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
  Grid[
    {{"Graphics", "Rasterize", "Array", "Rasterize vs Array"}, 
     Show[#, ImageSize -> 200, Frame -> True] & /@ 
       {graphics, raster, array, ColorCombine[{raster, array, array}]}}],
  {{picsize, 15}, 3, 50, 1}]
```

In this example, where a disk with a radius of 0.8 is shown in a square region [-1, 1]^2, it's visible that while `Graphics` and `Array` show nicely centred disk independently of the spatial sampling rate, `Rasterize` behaves weird.

The figure below shows the graphics object and its sampled versions as calculated by `Rasterize` and `Array` (Mathematica 12.1, Windows 10). The last plot overlays the two representations for comparison, so the misalignment is visible.

[image: An example of a graphics object and its sampled versions as calculated by <code>Rasterize</code> and <code>Array</code>. The last plot overlays the two representations for comparison.]

Is it a bug or do I miss something?

The reason I use `Rasterize` and not `Array` that `Rasterize` is much faster for large image sizes.

**Update and Workaround:** the misalignment can be corrected by changing the plot region by adding to it right and top margins of one pixel width. In the example above, for instance,  the perfect alignment can be obtained by using 
`Rasterize[
 Graphics[{GrayLevel[0], Disk[{0, 0}, .8]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1 + 2/picsize}, {-1 - 2/picsize, 1}}], 
  RasterSize -> {picsize, picsize}]`

So the MWE above can be modified to

```
Manipulate[
 graphics = 
  Graphics[{GrayLevel[0], Disk[{0, 0}, .8]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1 + 2/picsize}, {-1 - 2/picsize, 1}}, 
   GridLines -> {{-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}}];
 tr = Timing[
   raster = 
      Rasterize[graphics, RasterSize -> {picsize, picsize}];];
 tarr = Timing[
   array = 
      Image @ Boole @ 
      Array[{##} ∉ Disk[{0, 0}, .8] &, {picsize, picsize}, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];];
 Grid[
   {{"Graphics", 
     "Rasterize, " <> ToString[tr[[1]]] <> "s", 
     "Array, " <> ToString[tarr[[1]]] <> "s", 
     "Rasterize vs Array"}, 
     Show[#, ImageSize -> 200, Frame -> True] & /@ 
       {graphics, raster, array, ColorCombine[{raster, array, array}]}}], 
 {{picsize, 15}, 3, 50, 1}]
```

which results in
[image: Aligned Rasterize]

From all this, my guess is that `Rasterize` select the sampling points uniformly in the specified plot region, and uses them as top-left corners for the pixels. Effectively, this increases the total plot region.

Comment: I suggest you make your update into a self-answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm running V12.0 on MacOS 10.13 (High Sierra). I don't see any problem unless `picsize` rather small, forcing a coarse rasterization, which is documented as causing problems.

> When the settings for `RasterSize` or `ImageResolution` are small, the graphic will appear coarse, and text may be illegible. There may also be artifacts associated with aliasing.

I think this is the  problem you are encountering. Since it documented I don't thing we have call it feature rather than bug. The work-around is avoid coarse rasterization.

Comment: What I meant that `Rasterize` changes the plot region, and the disk is not centred in the resulted matrix, independently from the coarseness. The rightmost plot compares the image obtained by `Array` and  `Rasterize` with the same coarseness.